# Prolog raises out of local stack for no good reason

Tags: prolog, levenshtein-distance, failure-slice, non-termination

I'm trying to implement [Levenshtein distance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Levenshtein_distance) in  Prolog.

The implementation is pretty straightforward:

```
levenshtein(W1, W2, D) :-
    atom_length(W1, L1),
    atom_length(W2, L2),
    lev(W1, W2, L1, L2, D),
    !.

lev(_, _, L1, 0, D) :- D is L1, !.
lev(_, _, 0, L2, D) :- D is L2, !.
lev(W1, W2, L1, L2, D) :-
  lev(W1, W2, L1 - 1, L2, D1),
  lev(W1, W2, L1, L2 - 1, D2),
  lev(W1, W2, L1 - 1, L2 - 1, D3),
  charAt(W1, L1, C1),
  charAt(W2, L2, C2),
  ( C1 = C2 -> T is 0; T is 1 ),
  min(D1, D2, D3 + T, D).

% Returns the character at position N in the atom A
% The position is 1-based
% A: The atom
% N: The position at which to extract the character
% C: The character of A at position N
charAt(A, N, C) :- P is N - 1, sub_atom(A, P, 1, _, C).

% min(...): These rules compute the minimum of the given integer values
% I1, I2, I3: Integer values
% M:          The minimum over the values
min(I1, I2, M) :- integer(I1), integer(I2), ( I1 =< I2 -> M is I1; M is I2).
min(I1, I2, I3, M) :- min(I1, I2, A), min(I2, I3, B), min(A, B, M).
```

However, this code failures with this error:

```
?- levenshtein("poka", "po", X).
ERROR: Out of local stack
```

I'm using `SWIPL` implementation on `Mac OS X Sierra`.

Comment: I know nothing about Prolog but your code is obviously recursive, and the recursion is probably going unbounded and blowing the stack. I would double check the terminating conditions.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is a good reason for which your program does not work: your recursive calls lead into an infinite loop.

This is caused by those lines:

```
lev(W1, W2, L1 - 1, L2, D1),

lev(W1, W2, L1, L2 - 1, D2),

lev(W1, W2, L1 - 1, L2 - 1, D3),

min(D1, D2, D3 + T, D)
```

In Prolog things like `L1 - 1` are expressions that **do not** get evaluated to numbers. Therefore your code will recursively call `lev` with the third argument as `L1 -1`, then `L1 - 1 - 1`, etc. which does not match your terminating rules.

To fix this you need to use temporary variables where you evaluate the result of e.g. `L1 - 1`.

This fixes it:

```
lev(W1, W2, L1, L2, D) :-
    L11 is L1 - 1,
    L22 is L2 - 1,
    lev(W1, W2, L11, L2, D1),
    lev(W1, W2, L1, L22, D2),
    lev(W1, W2, L11, L22, D3),
    charAt(W1, L1, C1),
    charAt(W2, L2, C2),
    ( C1 = C2 -> T is 0; T is 1 ),
    D4 is D3 + T,
    min(D1, D2, D4, D).
```

Now this does this:

```
?- levenshtein("poka","po",X).
X = 0.
```

Which is probably not the result you want, but at least it does not error. I will leave it to you to fix your predicate.

Comment: found out it by myself via online debugger but that will be useful for future searchers

Answer (score 3):

There are several problems with your program.

### The loop

@Fatalize already gave you a reason, here is a general method how you can localize such problems, using a [failure-slice](/questions/tagged/failure-slice) by which some goals **`false`** are inserted into your program. If the remaining program loops, also the original version did:

```
?- levenshtein("poka","po",X), false.

levenshtein(W1, W2, D) :-
    atom_length(W1, L1),
    atom_length(W2, L2),
    lev(W1, W2, L1, L2, D), false,
    !.

lev(_, _, L1, 0, D) :- D is L1, !.
lev(_, _, 0, L2, D) :- D is L2, !.
lev(W1, W2, L1, L2, D) :-
  lev(W1, W2, L1 - 1, L2, D1), false,
  lev(W1, W2, L1, L2 - 1, D2),
  lev(W1, W2, L1 - 1, L2 - 1, D3),
  charAt(W1, L1, C1),
  charAt(W2, L2, C2),
  ( C1 = C2 -> T is 0; T is 1 ),
  min(D1, D2, D3 + T, D).
```

You have to modify something in the remaining, visible part. Otherwise, this problem will persist.

### Use lists!

Instead of using atoms or strings, better use lists to represent words.  The best is to add into your `.swiplrc` or `.sicstusrc`:

```
:- set_prolog_flag(double_quotes, chars).
```

In this manner, the following holds:

```
?- "abc" = [a,b,c].
```

### Avoid cuts

Cuts somehow, sometimes work, but such programs are hard-to-debug. In particular for beginners. Therefore, avoid them at all costs

### Use clean arithmetics

You are using the "olde" arithmetic of Prolog which is highly moded. Instead `use_module(library(clpfd))` to get purer code.